# Using javascript to manage navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage with 3 items in the navbar; Products, Partners and Support. I have moved this navbar to a seperate .html file; navbar.html and called it using load-navbar.js. I have done this to avoid code repetition. Is it possible to use javascript to show which navbar item is active? Is it possible to use switch statements to do this. If yes, how can I do this?

***navbar.html***

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default mc-header navbar-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mc-collapse-nav">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="../index.html"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.svg" alt="Company Logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="mc-collapse-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse mc-navbar-spacing">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
            <li><a class="mc-active" href="Items/products.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="partners.html">Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

***load-navbar.js***

```
$(function(){
    $("#main-nav").load("main-nav.html");
});
```

The mc-active class in products is added to the class to show that products.html is the active class.

Comment: Short answer: yes, it is possible to use javascript to highlight the active link. However, Why use Javascript to load something via AJAX?

Comment: @Jhecht I'm relatively new to web development and only have some understanding of Javascript. I dont get what u mean by load something via AJAX?

Comment: the `$('#main-nav').load()` call is what is commonly referred to as AJAX. It means Asyncrhonous Javascript and XML. Navigation bars are really important and unless you have a very specific reason to keep the bar out of your header template, I'd recommend putting it back.

Comment: @Jhecht okay. thats a clear explanation. What you're saying is it's best not keep the navbar is a seperate file and load it using javascript. Wont this cause problems due to code repetition?

Comment: what exactly makes it repetitious? I don't know the setup you have, but if you are using sectioned templates you should have at least 3 a header, a main body section, and a footer.

Comment: @Jhecht yes i do have that structure. What I meant by repetitious is that since I have 3 different pages; product.html, partners.html and support.html, the navbar part is the same throughout these 3 html files except which link is active. So if I'm in product.html, the Product link is active and highlighted.

Comment: generally you have your template engine mark which page is active before rendering.

Comment: @Jhecht how can I go about doing that?

Comment: What template engine are you using?

Comment: @Jhecht Sorry, I'm not sure what u mean by that. My web pages are all static pages.

Comment: then how are you combining them to make a website?

Comment: @Jhecht The source code is packaged and moved to the dreamhost webserver

Comment: I'm sorry @MichelleAshwini, but I do not know anything about dreamhost.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the current url in a variable:

```
var x = $(location).attr('href');
```

And then assign an "active" class to a link if the href matches the url, or if it's href is contained within the url, whichever fits your situation. You can use this link:

[css-tricks link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url/)

or this search:

[jquery active link google](https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=jquery%20active%20link)

for more info that might fit your situation better. I don't think you'd need more than a simple comparison between the window href and link href. Also I'd definitely follow the advice given in the comments.

Comment: I've tried $(function(){
    $("#main-nav").load("main-nav.html", function(){
          $('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('mc-active');
    });
});

The probem i have is the navbar dissapears when I click the link to another page in the navbar

Comment: Maybe try a simpler function: $("nav li").each(function() { var x = $(location).attr("href"); var y = this.children("a").attr("href"); if ( x.indexOf( y ) != -1 ) { this.addClass("active") }; });

Comment: Sorry if that doesn't seem simper. It is though, it's just checking if the string of the link href is contained within the url. If it is it adds the class "active". Up to you to style the active class.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that a shot. I'm having problems to just load the navbar into the page. Once I get that working, will try your solution and get back to you. :)

Comment: I hope it helps! Good luck. I think if you try out what the comments on your question suggest maybe the nav won't give you as much trouble. Maybe include it in a header file. You know your project best though.

Comment: Thanks. I've found out why the navbar cant load. The products.html is in a folder Item. And the main-nav.html is outside this folder. When I add the .. to the js file $(function(){
    $("#main-nav").load("../main-nav.html");
});
it loads the navbar correctly. Any suggestions how I can change this? Adding the .. then doesnt load the navbar in my index.html page

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think I can help much. I don't know your structure, and it sounds like you are using one very different then I ever have. I think I'd definitely suggest incorporating your main-nav html code into your header file if it isn't going to change on each page. The active link function would still work. Best of luck to you.